# Does AWS saves client's IP in SSH connections?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ip

I have an EC2 instance in AWS, and I would like to know who is accessing it, which IPs. Does AWS store this information, or only the machine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

AWS doesn't keep track of the SSH sessions.

[How to Monitor and Visualize Failed SSH Access Attempts to Amazon EC2 Linux Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-monitor-and-visualize-failed-ssh-access-attempts-to-amazon-ec2-linux-instances/)

> **SSH logs** – Reside on EC2 instances and **capture all SSH activities**. The logs include successful attempts as well as
>   unsuccessful attempts.

- **Debian** Linux SSH logs reside in `/var/log/auth.log`
- **CentOS** SSH logs are written to `/var/log/secure`
- **Amazon** Linux AMI also logs SSH sessions to `/var/log/secure`

Answer (score 1):

Open ssh allows you to view logs about who is logged in and when which is available in the following file /var/log/auth.log in case of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You could enable VPC flow logs, which would give you a log ofSSH connections that does not depend on the instance itself.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html